# SQLiteException: near "XY": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax-error

I wanna try some Sqlite request on android app,

**EDIT : My name columns :**

```
private static final String NOM_BDD = "sms.db";
private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;

private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final int NUM_COL_ID = 0;

private static final String TABLE_SMS_SENT = "table_sms_sent";
private static final String COL_DateSending = "dateSending";

private static final String TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED = "table_sms_received";
private static final String COL_DateReceiving = "dateReceiving";

private static final int NUM_COL_DateReceiving = 1;

private static final String COL_PROCESSED ="processed";
private static final int NUM_COL_PROCESSED = 2;

private static final String COL_PHONE ="phone";
private static final int NUM_COL_PHONE= 3;

private static final String COL_DATA ="data";
private static final int NUM_COL_DATA= 4;
```

My request is here :

```
private static final String CREATE_BDD_SMS_RECEIVED = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED + " ("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DateReceiving + " TEXT, "
        + COL_PROCESSED + " TEXT, " + COL_PHONE + "TEXT, " + COL_DATA + "TEXT)";
```

**Edit : deleting some spaces before 'TEXT'**

```
private static final String CREATE_BDD_SMS_RECEIVED = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED + " ("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DateReceiving + "TEXT, "
        + COL_PROCESSED + "TEXT, " + COL_PHONE + "TEXT, " + COL_DATA + "TEXT)";
```

And my OnCreate of myBaseSqlite class is here :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //on créé la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD sent et received
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD_SMS_RECEIVED);
}
```

And then on my MainActivity :

```
    CSmsReceiverDAO cSmsReceiverDAO = new CSmsReceiverDAO(this);
    CSmsReceived SmsReceived1 = new CSmsReceived.SmsReceivedBuilder().Id(0)
            .Data("coords XY").DateReceiving("janvier").Phone("+33565456").Processed("zz").build();

    cSmsReceiverDAO.open();

    try {
        cSmsReceiverDAO.persist(SmsReceived1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I believe the interesting error line is here :

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting zz=2 coords XY=4 janvier=1 +33565456=3

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "XY": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_sms_received(zz,coords XY,janvier,+33565456) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

EDIT : My persist code :
    @Override
    public void persist(CSmsReceived t) throws Exception {

```
    //Création d'un ContentValues (fonctionne comme une HashMap)
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //on lui ajoute une valeur associé à une clé (qui est le nom de la colonne dans laquelle on veut mettre la valeur)
    values.put(t.getDateReceiving(), NUM_COL_DateReceiving);
    values.put(t.getProcessed(), NUM_COL_PROCESSED);
    values.put(t.getPhone(), NUM_COL_PHONE);
    values.put(t.getData(), NUM_COL_DATA);

    //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
    bdd.insert(TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED, null, values);
}
```

My OnCreate seems to work, but my persist() doesn't work, it makes the error :

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting zz=2 coords XY=4 janvier=1 +33565456=3
                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "XY": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_sms_received(zz,coords XY,janvier,+33565456) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1838)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1711)
                                                                            at com.dev.boblinux.cador.bdd.CSmsReceiverDAO.persist(CSmsReceiverDAO.java:85)
                                                                            at com.dev.boblinux.cador.activities.CMainActivity.onCreate(CMainActivity.java:41)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But i don't see where is the error syntaxe..

Thanks for helping me ;)

Comment: please show `cSmsReceiverDAO.persist()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement is missing spaces before the word `TEXT` in two places. This will cause your table to have column names that differ from your defined constants.

Second: Your `INSERT` statement is not correct. The first group of terms in parentheses should be the column names, not the values you are inserting. I don't know your actual column names, but the statement should look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (data, data_receiving, phone, processed) 
    VALUES ('coords XY', '+33565456', 'janvier', 'zz');
```

Or simply

```
INSERT INTO table (data, data_receiving, phone, processed) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

**EDIT**

When you build your `ContentValues`, you have the arguments reversed for `values.put()`. It should be the column first and the value second, e.g.

```
values.put(t.getData(), NUM_COL_DATA); -> value.put(NUM_COL_DATA, t.getData());
```

Comment: "first" => fixed "second" => i don't understand what u mean, but i'm ok with you, `INSERT INTO table_sms_received(zz,coords XY,janvier,+33565456) VALUES (?,?,?,?)` should be `INSERT INTO table_sms_received(processed,data,date_receiving,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)` but i don't know how to fix it in my code =/

Comment: Edited for clarity since @boblinux included his persist code in the OP

Comment: no,i'm based on another code that works :     
        `values.put(COL_ISBN, livre.getIsbn());
        values.put(COL_TITRE, livre.getTitre());`

Comment: @boblinux you literally posted the exact same thing. Also, your edited OP now has more errors in your create table SQL.

Comment: i resolv some things [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394168/crud-my-find-function-on-a-sqlite-implementation-is-never-executed/35394725?noredirect=1#)