# CRUD: my `find()` function on a SQLite implementation is never executed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, crud

In a small app that intercepts SMS and persists them in a local database, 
I'm trying to implement a find method in my DAO.

this my all my CRUD code :

```
public class CSmsReceiverDAO implements IDAO<CSmsReceived> {
    private SQLiteDatabase bdd;
    private CMaBaseSQLite cMaBaseSQLite;
    private static final String NOM_BDD = "sms.db";
    private static final int VERSION_BDD = 1;

    private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    private static final int NUM_COL_ID = 0;

    private static final String TABLE_SMS_SENT = "table_sms_sent";
    private static final String COL_DateSending = "dateSending";

    private static final String TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED = "table_sms_received";
    private static final String COL_DateReceiving = "dateReceiving";

    private static final int NUM_COL_DateReceiving = 1;

    private static final String COL_PROCESSED ="processed";
    private static final int NUM_COL_PROCESSED = 2;

    private static final String COL_PHONE ="phone";
    private static final int NUM_COL_PHONE= 3;

    private static final String COL_DATA ="data";
    private static final int NUM_COL_DATA= 4;


    public CSmsReceiverDAO(Context context){
        //On créer la BDD et sa table
        cMaBaseSQLite = new CMaBaseSQLite(context, NOM_BDD, null, VERSION_BDD);
    }

    public void open(){
        //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
        bdd = cMaBaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        //on ferme l'accès à la BDD
        bdd.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getBDD(){
        return bdd;
    }

    @Override
    public CSmsReceived find(String date) throws Exception {
        //Récupère dans un Cursor les valeur correspondant à un livre contenu dans la BDD (ici on sélectionne le livre grâce à son titre)
        Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_DateReceiving, COL_PROCESSED, COL_PHONE, COL_DATA}, COL_DateReceiving + " LIKE \"" + date +"\"", null, null, null, null);
        return cursorToSms(c);
    }

    @Override
    public List<CSmsReceived> findAll() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(CSmsReceived t) throws Exception {

        //Création d'un ContentValues (fonctionne comme une HashMap)
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //on lui ajoute une valeur associé à une clé (qui est le nom de la colonne dans laquelle on veut mettre la valeur)
        values.put(t.getDateReceiving(), NUM_COL_DateReceiving);
        values.put(t.getProcessed(), NUM_COL_PROCESSED);
        values.put(t.getPhone(), NUM_COL_PHONE);
        values.put(t.getData(), NUM_COL_DATA);

        //on insère l'objet dans la BDD via le ContentValues
        bdd.insert(TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED, null, values);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(CSmsReceived t) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(CSmsReceived s, CSmsReceived t) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void refresh(CSmsReceived t) throws Exception {

    }

    //Cette méthode permet de convertir un cursor en un sms
    private CSmsReceived cursorToSms(Cursor c){
        //si aucun élément n'a été retourné dans la requête, on renvoie null
        if (c.getCount() == 0)
            return null;

        //Sinon on se place sur le premier élément
        c.moveToFirst();
        //On créé un sms
        //on lui affecte toutes les infos grâce aux infos contenues dans le Cursor
        CSmsReceived cSmsReceived = new CSmsReceived.SmsReceivedBuilder()
                .DateReceiving(c.getString(NUM_COL_DateReceiving))
                .Processed(c.getString(NUM_COL_PROCESSED)).Phone(c.getString(NUM_COL_PHONE))
                .Data(c.getString(NUM_COL_DATA)).build();
        //On ferme le cursor
        c.close();

        //On retourne le livre
        return cSmsReceived;
    }
}
```

My Sql Base code:

```
public class CMaBaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String COL_ID = "ID";

    private static final String TABLE_SMS_SENT = "table_sms_sent";
    private static final String COL_DateSending = "dateSending";

    private static final String TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED = "table_sms_received";
    private static final String COL_DateReceiving = "dateReceiving";
    private static final String COL_PROCESSED ="processed";

    private static final String COL_PHONE ="phone";
    private static final String COL_DATA ="data";

    private static final String CREATE_BDD_SMS_RECEIVED = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DateReceiving + "TEXT, "
            + COL_PROCESSED + "TEXT, " + COL_PHONE + "TEXT, " + COL_DATA + "TEXT);";

    private static final String CREATE_BDD_SMS_SENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_SENT + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DateSending + "TEXT, "
            + COL_PHONE + "TEXT, " + COL_DATA + "TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public CMaBaseSQLite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //on créé la table à partir de la requête écrite dans la variable CREATE_BDD sent et received
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD_SMS_RECEIVED);
        //db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD_SMS_SENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //On peut fait ce qu'on veut ici moi j'ai décidé de supprimer la table et de la recréer
        //comme ça lorsque je change la version les id repartent de 0
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_SENT + ";");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED + ";");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

it is my activity :

```
CSmsReceiverDAO cSmsReceiverDAO = new CSmsReceiverDAO(this);
CSmsReceived SmsReceived1 = new CSmsReceived.SmsReceivedBuilder()
        .Data("coords XY").DateReceiving("janvier").Phone("+33565456").Processed("zz").build();

cSmsReceiverDAO.open();

try {
    Log.i("test","try ok");
    cSmsReceiverDAO.persist(SmsReceived1);
    Log.i("test", "persist ok");
    CSmsReceived smsFromBdd = cSmsReceiverDAO.find(SmsReceived1.getDateReceiving());
    Log.i("test", "find ok");

    if (smsFromBdd !=null){
        Toast.makeText(this, smsFromBdd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "persist fail...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In my logs, the find method is never executed, but I don't understand why.

```
02-14 17:25:09.460 7571-7571/com.dev.boblinux.cador I/test: try ok
02-14 17:25:09.470 7571-7571/com.dev.boblinux.cador I/test: persist ok
```

**EDIT: Thanks to Hrundi V. Bakshi**:

my logs now:

`try ok
persist ok
find ok`

but there is nothing on my smsFromBdd :

```
        `if (smsFromBdd !=null){
            Toast.makeText(this, smsFromBdd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "persist fail...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }`
```

displays `persist fail...`

Comment: "You aren't separating your field names from their types" Can u explain what do you mean please? "the table is malformed" so where ?  i know that's my find that aborts my app but i don't see how to resolve, thanks for helping me bro :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't separating your field names from their types.
Therefore, the table is malformed.
And your app is aborting when executing `cSmsReceiverDAO.find()`

You need **spaces** between the field names and the field types.

```
private static final String CREATE_BDD_SMS_RECEIVED = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_RECEIVED + " ("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DateReceiving + " TEXT, "
        + COL_PROCESSED + " TEXT, " + COL_PHONE + " TEXT, " + COL_DATA + " TEXT);";

private static final String CREATE_BDD_SMS_SENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SMS_SENT + " ("
        + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DateSending + " TEXT, "
        + COL_PHONE + " TEXT, " + COL_DATA + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Then you need to uninstall your app and re-run it, in order for the database to be recreated.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i just uninstall and re-run : `try ok
persist ok
find ok` so, my  find method works, but `Log.i("test","sms content : " + smsFromBdd.toString());` is never executed =/ and now i really don't understand why ?? `smsFromBdd = null` so persist or find doesn't work

Comment: I guess there's a typo here: `\`if (smsFromBdd !=null){`

Comment: Sqlite is hard way implementation =/

Comment: No, why do you think so?

Comment: This is another question, though. But it seems that `smsFromBdd` hasn't been instanced properly